# Which items are in the three gifts of Haedrig?

Tags: diablo-iii

Having all three gifts results into a complete set.

- But which items are in the first gift?
- And which items are in the second gift?
- And which items are in the third gift?

For example a monk in season 12 will get the Uliana set.

- Which items of the Uliana set will I have after having the first gift?
- And which will I have after having the second gift?

Comment: Helm + Gloves -> Shoulders + Boots -> Chest + Legs (Assuming you clear the achievements in order from easiest to hardest)

Comment: @FoxMcCloud Thanks. Found the same here: https://www.diablowiki.net/Haedrig%27s_Gift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to community-ran [Season Tracker](http://d3resource.com/journey/index.php), you get the following items:

- Chapter 2: Helmet and Gloves
- Chapter 3: Boots and Shoulders
- Chapter 4: Chest and Legs

If a set has different pieces, the different piece was swapped for the missing piece (Shoulders, in the case of Season 11).

Comment: Nice season tracker.